# Printing multiline string in Java

Tags: java, printing, multiline

I have the following string

`String str = " Hello There \n How are you "`

I'm trying to print it using `System.out.println(str);` and `System.out.print(str);`
but all what I'm getting is `Hello There`

How can I print it all ?

Comment: That should work. How are you running your program?

Comment: @Keppil Using eclipse since I'm programming an Android application

Comment: It doesn't matter your IDE. Your code is right.

Comment: @Sergi Then why I'm only getting half of the sentence ?

Comment: Working proof :https://ideone.com/tDcigS

Comment: i done it too , http://ideone.com/EPKQFX

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because   not able to reproduce.

Comment: Not a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid `\n` and other platform dependent values:

```
final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String str = String.format("Hello There %s How are you", NEW_LINE);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = " Hello There \n How are you ";
    System.out.println(str);
```

As you tried, it is working fine. seems to be you are not read your out put well. Check [this](http://ideone.com/pn9v9X) out.

Answer (score 0):

To output a newline on Windows, you should use \r\n, which puts the cursor at the start of the new line. On Linux, you should use \n, which automatically does the job. `System.out.println()` automatically chooses the appropriate one and prints a new line at the end of the string. So your (platform independent) code should be:

```
System.out.println("Hello There");
System.out.println("How are you");
```